# Access application-specific data from another app

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I created a Chrome extension that makes use of google drive's application specific data:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

It's working as I'd hoped.  Now, I'm hoping to access that data from a node server, on my machine.  I found this example for working with google drive and node:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

That example works for me, but it has a different scope, listing files that are user visible on the drive.  What I want to do is to access the application specific data that is on google drive, that was created from my first app (the Chrome extension).

I'm not sure how to go about that.  After following the second tutorial, a second project was added to my Google developer console (https://console.developers.google.com).  I'm thinking, in order to access the data that is app specific, I need to mimic what the nodejs app is doing, but use a different scope and in the first project's (initially for the chrome extension) entry in the developer console, maybe add a second OAuth 2.0 client ID.  Is that right?  Are there other steps I should look into?

Comment: Use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` scope in your Node.js app and set up its credentials **in the same project** that you have for your Chrome extension in the Google Developer console.

Comment: What said @IvánNokonoko could work. They are the some project in the end, right? Also are you stroing the files as application data or just straight in user's drive?

Comment: I think they are effectively the same project, yes. I'm storing them as application data, using the appData scope.  So that the user cannot see the data, directly, and inadvertently mess with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your node app, you need to authorize the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` using **the OAuth credentials from the same project** where the application-specific data is stored.

That's the point about application-specific data: storing data that can only be accessed by the same application that created it. And the credentials are what identifies the application.

Beware, the word application here refers to the GCP project for which the credentials were created, not to whether you are using those credentials on a Chrome extension, a node server, or what have you. It's irrelevant that the storing process was done by a Chrome extension, and the access by a node app. The fact that they're using credentials from the same GCP project identifies both of them as the same application when it comes to accessing Drive API (I guess the confusion comes from the all-too-common use of the word application).

Anyway, once you've gone through the OAuth process, in order to search for files in the application data folder, you have to set the `spaces` field to `appDataFolder`, and call [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata#search_for_files_in_the_application_data_folder):

```
drive.files.list({
  spaces: 'appDataFolder',
  fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  pageSize: 100
}, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    res.files.forEach(function (file) {
      console.log('Found file:', file.name, file.id);
    });
  }
});
```

#### Reference:

- [Store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata)